# How to control the tableview reload data in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my map application I am calling web srvice which gives total available results in 5km of radius on map when launch. But If results are not available then it calls bigger radius in which I just want to show nearest 2 results in tableview cell. So how to control the loading of tableview data. Because when bigger radius called data count are 100 and I want only 2 results to display out of 100. Can anyone suggest me logic or tutorial. thanks in advance

Comment: In what manner you want to show that 2 results? I mean some sorting or something?

Comment: I hope he likes to show the nearest 2 results . A sorting must be there based on distance.

Comment: yes I am able to show the nearest two result on Map out of 100 results. But in my list view all 100 are displaying so I want only 2 in tablelist view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have searched for the larger radius, return 2 from `numberOfRowsInSection` in your `UITableViewDataSource` otherwise return the count of your array.  As long as your array is in the correct order (distance away) then it will only get called twice and so you will only return the nearest 2.

Because you are still storing all 100, but only displaying 2, that would mean you could then add a "show more" type button which will show the next 10, for example by returning 12 from `numberOfRowsInSection` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to save all the 100 data in your tableview array/dictionary ? Set a flag to detect whether it is from 5 km radius or greater radius. For the second case, store only 2 results.

Comment: How to set flag and where?? didnt get you

Comment: Ok. You must be checking somewhere in if-else whether the distance is less than 5 km or not. Take a BOOL isShortDistance and set it there if the distance is less than 5 km. Now, while parsing all the results in some array/dictionary, check for this flag. If set, fine. Else, store only the two results you need.